# 'Method not found: 'System.Security.PermissionSet System.AppDomain.get_PermissionSet()'.' when calling dbContext.Set<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am porting a web application from *.NET* to *.NET Core*. I first migrated *Entity Framework* to *EF Core*, and it is already working fine in the *.NET* version of the web app. Now recreated the web app, and I am getting an error like this in my repository class :

> *System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Security.PermissionSet System.AppDomain.get_PermissionSet()'.' when trying to run _dataContext.Set();*

Am I missing a reference to a different package or is there something missing in the framework? I really doubt I am the only one using *EF Core* in a *DotNet core* web app :), so any pointers to what I may be missing is appreciated.

```
public DbRepositoryBase(DbContext context)
{
    _dataContext = context;
    _dbset = _dataContext.Set<T>();
}
```

Comment: Have you add the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Comment: The project already had Microsoft.AspNetCore.App which I think is recommended for dotnet core 2.2 apps. Anyway, I tried your suggestion and didn't work either.

Comment: I am now wondering if libraries are effectively compiling for .NET Standard or not. The issue itself is happening in a library that is being used by a .NET Core and .NET project.